# JBoss-webservices.xml structure in JBoss eap 6

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jboss

```
<webservices xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://www.ibm.com/webservices   
/xsd/j2ee_web_services_1_1.xsd" version="1.1">
<webservice-description>
<webservice-description-name>CAPPLANService</webservice-description-name>
<wsdl-file>/wsdls/capplan.wsdl</wsdl-file>
<jaxrpc-mapping-file>WEB-INF/CAPPLANService.xml</jaxrpc-mapping-file>
<port-component>
<port-component-name>CAPPLANEndpointPort</port-component-name>
<wsdl-port>CAPPLANEndpointPort</wsdl-port>
<service-endpoint-interface>
com.eds.www.AirlineSOASchema.CAPPLAN.CAPPLANPortTypeImplPortType
</service-endpoint-interface>
<service-impl-bean>
<servlet-link>CAPPLANServiceServlet</servlet-link>
</service-impl-bean>
</port-component>
</webservice-description>
</webservices>
```

I am using this xml file.
But while compiling I am getting the below error,

```
16:17:22,837 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."capplan.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."capplan.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "capplan.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: JBWS021004: Failed to unmarshall vfs:/C:/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/capplan.war/WEB-INF/jboss-webservices.xml
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.webservices.JBossWebservicesFactory.load(JBossWebservicesFactory.java:111)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.JBossWebservicesDescriptorDeploymentProcessor.deploy(JBossWebservicesDescriptorDeploymentProcessor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWS021001: Unexpected element parsing vfs:/C:/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments/capplan.war/WEB-INF/jboss-webservices.xml: webservices
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.webservices.JBossWebservicesFactory.parse(JBossWebservicesFactory.java:160)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.webservices.JBossWebservicesFactory.load(JBossWebservicesFactory.java:109)
    ... 7 more
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong xmlns.

```
<webservices xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <!-- Rest of your file here -->
</webservices>
```